# Как создать 2 разных сервиса в 1 проекте?

Tags: java, c#, rest

Добрый день.Пишем новый проект.Проект огромный и пишется на 2х языках Java и `С#`.Собственно сам вопрос пишутяс сервисы на двух разных языках.Как быть :?как их собрать под один проект?Неужели нету технологий для такого?чтобы был проект и туда модульно заливали сервисы частями .Буду благодарен за информацию"!

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону [микросервисов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices). Тогда приложения смогут взаимодействовать друг с другом несмотря на языки реализации. Но проекты в ide будут все равно разные.

Comment: Собирать в общую папку. Либо после сборки запускать (автоматически, либо вручную) .cmd файл, которым копировать готовые файлы в общую папку в соответствии со структурой проекта.

Comment: @StasDorozhko а нету никаких контейнеров для этого ?пусть коды у каждого будут свои в своих АИДи но деплоить будем на один общий сервер (контейнер)

Comment: Похоже, вам нужен Docker. У нас в данный момент используются сервисы на C# (.net core) и Java. Все заливаются в докер и далее на Amazon ECS.